# Get cursor's position when enter key was pressed

Tags: iphone, swift

I would like to let user split UITextField when they press enter key in edit mode. Something like:

> foo|bar     (vertical bar being cursor) - now I press enter

and I'd like to create new UITextField underneath, which should look like this:

> foo
>
> bar

But I can't get cursor's position when I press enter. I tried this snippet:

```
    if let selectedRange = field.selectedTextRange {
        let cursorPosition = field.offset(from: field.beginningOfDocument, to: selectedRange.start)
        print("\(cursorPosition)")
    }
```

But it returns `6` instead of `3`. It appears pressing enter will make cursor jump to the end of current word first and then executing my snippet. I tried to put it in `textFieldShouldReturn`, `textFieldShouldEndEditing` and also in event of UITextField `Did End On Exit` with the same results.

Is there a way to prevent the cursor's jump or is there some other way of solving it? I'm a beginner in iPhone development, so I may be missing something obvious...

Comment: Why not use UITextView when it provides you the same functionality by default?

Comment: Because UITextField is in fact in a tableViewCell which lets user to do some operations on the UITextField.

Comment: Did you try to put it on `textFieldShouldEndEditing(_:)`?

Comment: @DennisKeithGaso no, will do

Comment: @DennisKeithGaso Tried it ... the same behaviour :(

Comment: Implement `func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String)` - the range indicates the current cusor position, which you can store somewhere and retrieve when enter is tapped. This is not 100% accurate, of course.

Comment: `Because UITextField is in fact in a tableViewCell which lets user to do some operations on the UITextField.` Why is that a reason for not using the UITextView? You know you can use auto-resizing cells which can increase in size as the size of your textview increases, right?  Don't get me wrong, I am not here to criticise your choice, I am just trying to understand if you have really made the right choice. XY Problems are super common.

Comment: @Gereon When pressing enter without any edits to the text beforehand range.location still gives me incorrect value.

Comment: @NSNoob I understand, the screen I'm working on is called Assign fields. User assigns OCRed text split to lines to fields in app. Sometimes it is needed to split text to several lines so I figured using enter key on keyboard would be the most intuitive.